# box-shadow will overlap instead of overwrite

Tags: css

I don't know how to describe clearly. I will use following code to demonstrate:

```css
.parent { position: relative; }
.box { position: absolute; width: 100px;  height: 100px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px black; }
.single { left: 200px; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a box">
  </div>
  <div class="b box">
  </div>
  <div class="single box">
  </div>
</div>
```

As a result, the left boxes have darker box-shadow because the box shadows are overlapped instead of overwrite.

Is there a solution? The html structure cannot be updated. The only thing that can update is the a and b. For example:
.a { ... }
.b { ... }

Comment: what is the behavior you are hoping for? If you overlap multiple box shadows they will both be applied. A lot of box shadow effects are actually made using multiple overlapping box-shadows.

If you don't want the shadows to overlap, is there any way you can not have box a and box b overlapping?

Comment: I don't want the overlapping effect. Can I add some code to disable this behavior? The boxes' positions can not be updated, and the box-shadow have to be set for both a and b.

Comment: Well the box-shadow itself is inherently an "overlapping" effect as you describe it. In your example, even the box on the right has the box shadow "overlapping" because it is overlapping on the white background behind it. You can't disable that without simply turning off the box-shadow. Maybe you need a different way of creating a shadow. 

Could you describe more about why you need it this way? I'm sure there is another solution someone could come up with.

Comment: What is the expected result? Just post as img, so you can get expected answer

Comment: Well, my user case is quite special. I'm creating a table-kind app using html. It has cells as its skeleton, and it will also have content which will created on top of the cells. The style of cells can be customized, for example it can have a box shadow style or a border radius style. The problem is, sometimes the content will across multi cells and it have to inherit the cell style to make it looks perfect. The only problem is the box shadow style, just as I described.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "The problem is, sometimes the content will across multi cells and it have to inherit the cell style to make it looks perfect.", but it sounds like that's the part where something needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting an opaque background behind each box-shadow so that the box-shadows don't overlap. Here's an example where I apply a background color to the "box" divs and place children divs with class "shadow" inside the boxes. The children divs have the box-shadow effect.

```css
.parent { position: relative; }
.box { position: absolute; width: 100px;  height: 100px; background: #ffffff;}
.single { left: 200px; }
.shadow { position: absolute;  margin: 10px; width: 80px; height: 80px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px black; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a box">
    <div class="shadow" />
  </div>
  <div class="b box">
    <div class="shadow" />
  </div>
  <div class="single box">
    <div class="shadow" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The html structure cannot be updated. You may image that the a is a static div and b is a dynamic div with a position:absolute style which is created just on top of a.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Working solution with JS

```js
const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
for(let i = 1; i < boxes.length; i++) {

    if(boxes[i].getBoundingClientRect().x === boxes[i-1].getBoundingClientRect().x 
    && boxes[i].getBoundingClientRect().y === boxes[i-1].getBoundingClientRect().y) {
      boxes[i].style.boxShadow = "none";
    }

}
```

```css
.parent { position: relative; }
        .box { position: absolute; width: 100px;  height: 100px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px black; }
        .single { left: 200px; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="a box">
    </div>
    <div class="b box">
    </div>
    <div class="single box">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well box a has to have the shadow style...

Comment: Aha, I see. If something has to be a certain way you need to specify that in your question :)